# Google results of search queries in other websites?

Tags: seo, google

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I think the answer will be interesting, so I had to ask.

I came across something while searching for this single character:

https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%80%90

These are my search results (from Australia):

[image: google search results]

I noticed after the first two generic expected results there were strange results from websites which have their own search query URLs. I go to the third result and it's got a sort of advertisement for a place in south korea:

```
┎신속하게┚●GGULFO.COM●당동출장샵❒당동오피스텔✁당동키스방✙당동출장샵✿당동스파【당동출장샵♐당동풀쌀롱✞당동휴게실✒당동출장샵
```

Intrigued, I continue and search for what the website is: https://www.google.com/search?q=GGULFO.COM and get more confusing results.

[image: google search results]

What is going on here?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it appears to be about results found in a Google search not related to your own website.